# Как спрятать секретное число от декомпиляторщиков в Android приложении?

Tags: java, android, безопасность

Сейчас в моем клиентском приложении лежит очень секретное число. Лежит оно в ресурсах, `strings.xml`, надо срочно что-то придумать, чтобы ковыряльщики-хакеры не смогли ничего найти, или хотя бы приостановить их злодеяния :) Число это состоит из 50 цифр, передается серверу строкой как API ключ. Я придумал следующее:

Создать статический метод, возвращающий это число путем нехитрых операций. Надо будет сделать вызовы других методов из разных библиотек, даже модифицировать библиотеки поддержки, причем сделать большие переплетения из одной библиотеки в другую. Пускай для еще большего усложнения эти библиотеки будут написаны на C++.

Или есть более грамотное решение? Я вот замечал где-то что апктул не умеет декомпилить `boolean`, там что-то вроде 0 и 1 получается, точно не помню.

Вообщем, что можно придумать? А то вот такие манипуляции каждый раз при запросе на сервер длительны будут, а если при старте игры его получать и хранить в переменной, то вроде есть какие-то утилиты для просмотра ячеек dalvik памяти приложения.

Comment: `Создать статический метод, возвращающий это число путем нехитрых операций.` Если весь код получения этого числа будет сосредоточен в одном методе, то толку-то... лучше 2-3 оператора в разных точках программы, заполняющие соответственно 2-3 глобальные переменные (да ещё так, чтобы эти значения казались чем-то иным), и выражение, которое в нужном месте по их значениям собирает это число в момент, когда оно потребуется.

Comment: это API ключ от вашего или какого-то третьего, стороннего сервиса?

Comment: @Sergiks, от моего

Comment: Удобнее будет делать авторизацию устройств на сервере - а присутствие вашего API ключа будет начальным этапом для получение этой авторизации. У нас в проекте API ключ привязывается к пользователю (агенту), для которого могут быть проставлены уровни доступа и др. Таким образом не надо будет изворачиваться, крутится и вертеться, пытаясь выдумать как на КЛИЕНТЕ ваш "секрет" бы не украли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В статье [«Обзор способов защиты программных продуктов на Java»](http://kes.narod.ru/people/lexus/JavaSourceCodeProtection.htm) можно почитать по основным способам защиты приложения.

Выдержка из конца статьи:

> **Сценарий защиты**
>
> Подводя итог хотел бы вкратце обрисовать сценарий достаточно эфективой борьбы против декомпиляции:
>
> 1. Предварительно поместить в готовый java код несколько глухих классов.
> 2. Откомпилировать их и запихать в отделный архив.
> 3. Затем «затемнить» java код используя вспомогательные средства, например, Crema.
> 4. Отдельно реализовать классы которые будут храниться в native методе и получаться при помощи механизма схожего с ClassLoader.
> 5. Откомпилировать их.
> 6. Откомпилировать остальной java код.
> 7. Применить метод изменения байт-кода.
> 8. Запаковать остальной java код.
> 9. Зашифровать классы которые храниться в native методе, используя любой алгоритм, например RSA и поместить его в native код.
> 10. Реализовать в native методе проверку целостности архива с java кодом
> 11. Откомпилировать native код.
> 12. Удалить архив с глухими классами.
> 13. Создать лицензию.
> 14. Теперь всё это можно запускать.

Comment: "например RSA" -- а ключи куда?

Comment: используйте рефлексию, запутывание кода, данные представляйте в виде массива байтов с мусором и тп и тд. Т.е. это в нативном метода для закрытого ключа, а публичные можно хранить as is

Answer (score 7):

Принято считать, что всё, что находится в клиенте – раскрыто и поддаётся подделке.

Если ваш сценарий предполагает запросы к API какого-то третьего сервиса, то либо смиритесь с раскрытием API ключа (он ведь передаётся в запросах в открытом виде и его можно сниффером снять), или, как вариант, проксируйте запросы к сервису через свои прокси, дописывающие API ключ налету.

Comment: А если ключ зашифровать, отправить и расшифровать на сервере? Снифф в этом случае бесполезен. И все же насчет С++ библиотек - вроде хорошая идея :) Их же нельзя декомпилить :)

Comment: @Flippy: C++-библиотеки прекрасно декомпилируются, IDA, например.

Answer (score 5):

> апктул не умеет декомпилить boolean, там что-то вроде 0 и 1 получается, точно не помню

Это не "не умеет", 0 = false, 1 = true, что еще надо.

> Лежит оно в ресурсах, strings.xml

Это пожалуй самое неудачное, Apktool это первое с чего начинают, даже самые недалекие, которые не пойдут дальше и вообще программировать толком не умеют.

> А то вот такие манипуляции каждый раз при запросе на сервер длительны будут

Вдобавок, могут даже навредить, HTTP хорошо сниффится, это тоже начальный уровень реверс-инжиниринга.

> Вообщем, что можно придумать?

В основном эффективны два способа:

- Искажение информации (дезинформация). Изобразите, что это число вовсе не так важно и вовсе не то, что они ищут, а что-то неинтересное.
- Уменьшение количества информации. Чем меньше знает разведчик, тем дальше он от цели. Была задача, где приложение работало с неким сервером, а еще должно было слать на некий сервер данные при попытке взлома, так я сделал, чтобы это был один и тот же сервер, и данные слались POST-запросом на корневой URL (с index.php), в котором такой запрос отличался от других и обрабатывался иначе, и поди разберись в том же сниффере где какой запрос и что за что отвечает, а если бы было "acrbtrverbtr.ru/eih8eh89e8hvev.php" - то сразу бы бросалось в глаза, это не лучше чем назвать прямо "security-server.ru/report.php".

> есть какие-то утилиты для просмотра ячеек dalvik памяти приложения

Есть, отладчики называются, но отладка уже далеко не всем доступна, в отличие от декомпиляции JD-Gui и Fernflower'ом, и дизассемблирования в IDA Pro.

Answer (score 4):

Есть несколько вариантов разной степени продвинутости и применимости:

1. Зашифровать ваш API key, но это только кажется, что решает проблему, потому, что пароль для шифрования все равно будет лежать в коде/ресурсах, так что история превращается в рекурсивную сказочку [про попа с собакой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0). Видел варианты с глубиной рекурсии до 3-х :)
2. Можно конечно в качестве пароля использовать [идентификатор устройства](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) - проблема в этом случае возникает с развертыванием вашей аппы. Надо заранее знать `deviceId` и сгенерировать для него шифрованный *API key* - то есть имеет крайне ограниченную применимость. Правда, если речь идет о корпоративных устройствах для ограниченного круга лиц - вполне работает
3. Еще способ - хранить ключи во внешнем сервере и при первом запуске приложения получать их оттуда (требуется *https* и какой-нибудь небольшой облачный сервисочек с высунытым наружу Rest'ом)
4. Другой вариант использовать коммерческие обфускаторы, типа [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard), которые в отличие от ProGuard умеют также и шифровать код.

Answer (score 0):

Извращение, но как вариант: ваш ключ, превратить в байтовый массив, который в свою очередь попробовать превратить в Java-байт код (получится билиберда, но вдруг реально), а потом с помощью `ASM` в своем приложении инжектить его куда-нибудь и обратно превращать в ключ. Таким образом у вас явно не будет ключа, а разборки с `ASM` еще пусть попробуют провернуть ваши злоумышленники.